# Find the maximum value of $\sin 7A+\sin 7B+\sin 7C$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, maxima-minima

Found this problem in the national high school math competition today... I was completely dumbfounded.

Find the value of the smallest interior angle of triangle $ABC$ when $\sin 7A+\sin 7B+\sin 7C$ takes the maximum value.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to tackle this problem? This is where I'm stuck at: $$\sin 7A+\sin 7B+\sin 7C=-4\sin\frac{7A}{2}\sin\frac{7B}{2}\sin\frac{7C}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Note,

$$I=\sin 7A+\sin 7B+\sin 7C$$
$$=\sin7A - 2\cos\frac{7A}2 \cos\frac{7(B-C)}2
\le \sin7A - 2\cos\frac{7A}2 $$

where the equality corresponds to $B=C$ and $\cos\frac{7A}2<0$ is assumed (to be verified below). Set the derivative of the RHS to zero,

$$\cos7A +\sin\frac{7A}2 = 1-2\sin^2\frac{7A}2 +\sin\frac{7A}2 =0$$

which yields $\sin\frac{7A}2 = -\frac12$. The valid solutions are $A=\frac\pi3,\>\frac{11\pi}{21},\>\frac{19\pi}{21} $, of which the first and the third, or $A=B=C=\frac\pi3$ and $A=\frac{19\pi}{21}, \>B=C=\frac{\pi}{21}$ respectively, produce the maximum value for the sum,

$$I \le \sin \frac{7\pi}3 +\sin \frac{7\pi}3+\sin \frac{7\pi}3=
\sin \frac{19\pi}3 +\sin \frac{\pi}3+\sin \frac{\pi}3=\frac{3\sqrt3}2$$

Indeed, $\cos\frac{7A}2<0$ for $A = \frac\pi3,\>\frac{19\pi}{21}$ as assumed earlier.

Comment: Such advanced math  I'm still a high school student so I haven't learned multivariable calculus yet. Can you give a more traditional approach?

Comment: @temrock02 - I simplified the solution to use only single-variable calculus.

Comment: The logic doesn't sound right to me. You *assume* that $\cos(7A/2)<0$ and find the maximum given that restriction, then verified the found maximum is when $\cos(7A/2)<0$??? Also, 1) derivative is not correct, 2) derivative $0$ does not guarantee maximum (minimum, ...)

Comment: Double checked the zero-derivative equation, which is correct. The maximum is due to the negative second derivative. You may prefer full rigor, which I understand.

Comment: And what is "the value of the smallest interior angle 
of $\triangle ABC$ 
when $\sin7A+\sin7B+\sin7C$ takes the maximum value"?

Comment: All three angles are equal.

Comment: "Smallest interior angle $A=B=C=\tfrac\pi3$"
is definitely incorrect answer. 
Check out, for example,
$A=B=\tfrac\pi{21}$.

Comment: Looks like may have overlooked other solutions of $\sin(7A/2)=-1/2$. Will take an another look. Thanks

Comment: If this helps, also, triangles with
$A=\tfrac\pi{21},B=\tfrac\pi{21}+\tfrac{2\pi k}7$, $k=0..3$
have the same maximal value of the sum, $\tfrac{3\sqrt3}2$.